# Argumento inválido fornecido para foreach

Tags: php, array

Criei um `foreach` para percorrer um `array` que possui 2 elemento porem eu queria que meu foreach pega-se apenas o primeiro elemento, eu tentei utilizar o `[0]` porem meu retorno foi esse erro:

ERRO:

```
arning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Apache2\htdocs\teste.php on line 44
```

Meu código:

```php
foreach($lista_quantidade[0] as $quantidade_unidade){
       $quantidade_unidade = intval($quantidade_unidade);
       $quantidade_unida_diferen = $quantidade - $quantidade_unidade;
       echo "Diferença de quantidade: $quantidade_unida_diferen" . "<br>";
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você deseja pegar o elemento [0] do seu array, pq precisa percorre-lo? Você não precisa de um foreach para ter esse valor.

Comment: tem razão nao havia me ligado